# Django Rest Framework AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

День добрый!

Проблемы с сериализацией, не применяется лист фильтр, хотя делаю всё по примеру.

```
class FilterSerializerProductCategory(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(parent=None)
        return super().to_representation(data)


class RecursiveSerializerProductCategory(serializers.Serializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    children = RecursiveSerializerProductCategory(many=True)

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FilterSerializerProductCategory
        model = ProductCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'code', 'parent', 'children')
```

Выдаёт ошибку: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

view.py:

```
class ProductCategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCategorySerializer
```

model.py:

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    """категории продуктов"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

Comment: Можно ссылку на пример, из которого делаете?

Comment: там видео на ютубе youtube.com/watch?v=Lpfi8E_3ykY

Comment: С видео сложнее. Пока могу только сказать, что у Вас, вероятно, на место второго аргумента должен передаваться объект какого-то специального типа, а передаётся простой список.

Comment: в list_serializer_class ?

Comment: В методе `to_representation`

Comment: а вы пробовали смотреть что у вас в `data`? какой тип объекта, какие там вообще данные и можно ли к ним применить метод `filter`?

Comment: там находится catalog.ProductCategory.None

Comment: а если так  print(data.all()), то там список из моей таблицы TreeQuerySet

Comment: Начинаю понимать, а как в data передать всю таблицу включая parent

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в вюшку `pagination_class = None`

```py
class ProductCategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None
```